# what's wrong with Destructors? (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributes, attr

As an exercise, I'm trying to build a complete instance of the "ID" object, and so far I've been able to understand the calling terms of `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` known as `Destructors`, and I follow it with a childish trick. But I got to the point where instead of `__set__`, `__del__` is called and in `__get__` it gets the first parameter `None`. I'm totally confused; Help if you can

```
>>> class ID:
...     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
...             print('__get__(%s, %s)' % (instance, owner))
...             return id(self) + id(instance)  # Just so it is not empty
...     def __set__(self, instance, value):
...             print('__set__(%s, %s)' % (instance, value))
...     def __del__(self):
...             print('__del__()')
... 
>>> class test:
...     def __new__(cls, id):
...             # if I cannot use Destructors as normal attr,
...             # so I make a new instance
...             return type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls.__dict__ | {'id': id})
... 
>>> t = test(id=ID())
>>> t.id
__get__(None, <class '__main__.test'>)
141886578966904
>>> # worked but "instance" is None
>>> t.id = 10
__del__()
>>> # ???
```

Comment: You typed `instabce` not `instance` - although I'm confused that it did not give you a `NameError`

Comment: I copy this codes from different locations of consol. thanks

Comment: `__del__` is not a destrutor.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense at all. `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__` are parts of the the *descriptor protocol*, which is a protocol for controlling attribute access using descriptor objects. Why are you using a class `__new__` here at all??

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 mistakes here:

1. `__delete__` is Destructors and not `__del__`
2. `__new__` returns a TYPE object. (`object.__new__(CLS) -> OBJ`)

Comment: `__delete__` is not a destructor